# Who are the two brothers?

Tags: riddle, wordplay

Identify the two brothers, as they describe themselves:

### First brother:

> I am:
>
> 1. a hybrid,
> 2. Lord of Horse after an account,
> 3. a cue running only sideways, same as you do,
> 4. "One one, one see, / Are zero two many?"
> 5. beyond past.

### Second brother:

> I am:
>
> 1. normal to my brother,
> 2. descending,
> 3. on the bird,
> 4. with a tail belonging to myself,
> 5. not so happy.

### Both of them:

> Need a clue? We are!

---

Remark:

1. This may turn out to be easier than I think, simply because there are too many hints.
2. Please try to explain all (or most of ) the hints.

Comment: My first thought is that they are types of lines, simply based on normal to my brother being at 90 degrees.

Comment: @sgr a tree is normal to the plains, but neiter are lines

Comment: @Jasen well my argument to that would be just having something be 'normal' in your sense would be so broad a hint you may as well not have it there at all and it wouldn't make solving the question any harder. Therefore, 'normal' being a special case of the word normal makes more sense.

Comment: I was using the term gemetrically, the plains are level and the tree grows perpendicular.

Comment: Is it an undead, disabled, half-elf, stable master and a hobbit riding a tired eagle?  If not then this may just be tricky enough.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you are

> ACROSS and DOWN.

a hybrid

> a cross

Lord of Horse after an account

> A/C + Ross, I assume, though I have no idea why Ross = Lord of Horse.

a cue running only sideways, same as you do,

> initial letters: **a** **c**ue **r**unning **o**nly **s**ideways (and also describes how an "across" clue in a crossword functions)

"One one, one see, / Are zero two many?"

> one one = "a", one see = "c", are = "r", zero = "o", two many = "ss" (two plurality markers)

beyond past.

> Not sure how this one works. -- Hugh Meyers quite rightly points out in comments that in some contexts "across" can mean "beyond" and "past": "your destination is across that bridge".

normal to my brother

> "Normal" meaning "perpendicular", as ACROSS and DOWN are.

descending

> duh.

on the bird

> "I say, I say, I say, how do you get down from an elephant?" "You don't, you get down off a duck."

with a tail belonging to myself,

> d-**own**

not so happy

> "Help me if you can, I'm feeling dow-ow-own."

Need a clue? We are!

> A crossword's clues are divided into "across" and "down" clues.

Comment: I think on the bird refers to down feathers

Comment: So do I. That's the point of the (admittedly not very funny) joke I quoted in my answer.

Comment: "beyond" and "past" are synonyms for the word in its positional meaning.

Comment: You're right. I'll adjust my answer accordingly. [... done.]

Comment: Great!  Something you (probably) missed, can you find "down" in the clues? (ofc you can :D)

Comment: Oh yeah. Nice. (I did indeed miss it.)

Comment: BTW, [Ross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ross_(name)) etymologically means "Lord of the Horse".

Comment: It seems obviously too short to mean something so complicated, and the history of that bit of the WP page doesn't inspire confidence. [tappity tap google google tap tap tap] OK, so German "Ross" just means "horse" and it looks as if some people have been called "de Ross", "de Ros", "de Rose" because they bred or kept horses; I think the "Lord" bit was made up by the person who wrote that part of the Wikipedia page :-). (Usually the surname "Ross" means "from a place called "Ross", and the place name "Ross" means "headland".)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out... I should've paid attention to that..:|

Comment: It's OK -- no harm done. (Apologies for being nitpicky.)

Answer (score 4):

## First Brother :

> . (dot)

- a hybrid :

  > A dot, in geometry, is an intersection of a plane and a line.
- Lord of Horse after an account,

  > No idea.
- a cue running only sideways, same as you do

  > When you are writing, you move from left to right (sideways). On completing the sentence you put a full stop. (cue = sign = punctuation sign)
- "One one, one see, / Are zero two many?"

  > 1 1, 1 c = 11, 1c = 17, 28 (on converting from hexadecimal to decimal).
  > 17 + 28 = 45
  >  0 2 = 02.
  > 45 + 02 = 47
  >  02 are many. So the number between 45 and 47 is 46, which is the ASCII value of `.`
- beyond past.

  > A full stop can be used to indicate things that are past. When you "put a full stop" to something, you mean that it is over.

## Second Brother:

> | (Vertical line)

- normal to my brother

  > The line is above `.` in `!`.
- descending

  > The line is drawn from up to down. Also, in some fonts, it is thick at the top, and narrows as it comes down.
- on the bird

  > Probably means on the dot?
- with a tail belonging to myself

  > The **.** is a tail to **|** in the **!**
- not so happy.

  > It is not happy because it has to keep standing!

## Both of them:

Need a clue? We are!

> They are **!**

Comment: Nice try, unfortunately not the intended answer.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously not the answer, but here's what I immediately thought of

**First Brother:**

> Integers

a hybrid

> A hybrid of negative and positive numbers

Lord of Horse after an account

> No idea

a cue running only sideways, same as you do

> Numberlines that include all integers run sideways infinitely

"One one, one see, / Are zero two many?"

> Not entirely sure. Zero is not too many for an integer, but it is for negative numbers.

beyond past.

> This can either mean so far in the past that it is beyond "the past" (negative infinity), or it can mean the present (0) and the future (positive infinity)

**Second Brother:**

> Negative numbers

normal to my brother

> The set of all negative numbers is a subset of all integers

descending

> Should be obvious

on the bird

> No idea

with a tail belonging to myself

> The negative sign can appear like a tail, and only negative numbers have this

not so happy

> Have a "negative" outlook on life